# visual studio 2015 different theme for same user account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, themes

Is there a way to change the theme for Visual Studio 2015 without changing it for other people that are using the same account?

At my work we all use the same account and every time I change my theme to dark it also changes it for someone else in the office (although there are only three of us and the other guy is not effected somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uncheck the **Environment** - **Synchronized settings** - **Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio** option. See [Synchronized Settings in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for.